# how to get the photo in google places search api with radius tag

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-api-2

**Google Places API**
when I use `radius=5000` as parameter with this api, it does not provide the `photos` tag in response, whereas if I use `rank=distance` it provides the `photos` tag, but the result only comes across the limited radius.

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.2773008,73.0336478&rankby=distance&types=bar&key=XXXXXXX
- In the above url we get the `photos` tag , but we get only limited radius records.
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.2773008,73.0336478&radius=50000&types=bar&key=XXXXXXXX
- And if I use above url it does not provide the `photos` tag.
  How can I got the `photos` tag with desired radius?

  If it is not possible then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem and the only workaround for me is to call Details api with the "place_id" from search and check if the place has or not photos. Of course, this is not a proper solution because it needs to make unnecessary calls and it's way too slow.

PS. You should not post you API Key.

Comment: currently i also use this process, but this make my app is very slow cause of unnecessary calls

Answer (score 0):

Missing photos (and ratings) is a known issue.  Star the below issue to be notified when it's resolved.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6853